# Does ISNULL on MySql work differently with collation latin_swedish_ci and utf8_general_ci

Tags: mysql, mariadb, collation

I have two databases on MariaDB with InnoDB as engine, with both DB having  `latin_swedish_ci` as collation, but one has `latin_swedish_ci` as table collation and other `utf8_general_ci` as table collation, when I execute left excluding join on database with the following query:

```
SELECT `ct`.`name` 
FROM `csv_temp` as `ct` 
left join `trans_recs` as `tr` on `ct`.`name` = `tr`.`name` 
where `tr`.`name` is null and `ct`.`fk_project_id` = 1
```

I get correct results on DB and table both with `latin_swedish_ci` collation but empty set on DB with `latin_swedish_ci` and table with `utf8_general_ci`.

Is there an explanation for his behaviour. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Collation refers to column content. If a column is NULL then it does not have a content. So no - IS NULL is collation independend

Comment: @juergend thanks for the info, appreciate it. But my concern is why does the query work with DB and table both with latin_swedish_ci collation but empty set on DB with latin_swedish_ci and table with utf8_general_ci.

Comment: So, the `NULL` is a red herring?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each of the two tables.  This may answer your question.  If not we will have more to work with.

Answer (score 0):

> Does ISNULL on MySql work differently with collation latin_swedish_ci and utf8_general_ci

It does not. `ISNULL` will work when the cell is null regarding of the collation.

> I get correct results on DB and table both with latin_swedish_ci collation but empty set on DB with latin_swedish_ci and table with utf8_general_ci.

Maybe the default is an empty string and not `NULL` with the collation `latin_swedish_ci`